# Relation Between Complex Gradients

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on an exercise from *Fundamentals of Complex Analysis* by Saff and I am having trouble reaching the desired form. Here is the problem statement:

First let $z = x + iy$ and $w = u + iv$ be related such that $u = u(x,y)$, $v = v(x,y)$, $x = x(u,v)$, and $y = y(u,v)$ are one-to-one analytic mappings. Let $\phi(x,y)$ be a twice-continuously differentiable function carried over in the $w$-plane to the function $\psi(u,v):=\phi(x(u,v,),y(u,v))$. Use the chain rule and the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that $\nabla \psi = \nabla \phi \times\overline{\dfrac{dz}{dw}}$.

Here is what I have tried so far. I am given $\nabla \psi = \dfrac{d\psi}{du} + i\dfrac{d\psi}{dv}$ and $\nabla \phi = \dfrac{d\phi}{dx} + i\dfrac{d\phi}{dy}$, so I began by trying to apply the chain rule to the left hand side.

$$\begin{align*} \dfrac{d\psi}{du} + i\dfrac{d\psi}{dv} &= \dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{du} + \dfrac{d\phi}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{du} + i\bigg[\dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{du} + \dfrac{d\phi}{dy}\dfrac{dy}{dv}\bigg] \\ &= \dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\bigg[\dfrac{dx}{du} + i\dfrac{dx}{dv}\bigg] +\dfrac{d\phi}{dy}\bigg[\dfrac{dy}{du} + i\dfrac{dy}{dv}\bigg] \\ &= \dfrac{d\phi}{dx}\bigg[\dfrac{dx}{du} - i\dfrac{dy}{du}\bigg] +i\dfrac{d\phi}{dy}\bigg[\dfrac{dx}{du} - i\dfrac{dy}{du}\bigg] \\ &= \bigg[\dfrac{d\phi}{dx} + i\dfrac{d\phi}{dy}\bigg]\bigg[\dfrac{dx}{du} - i\dfrac{dy}{du}\bigg] \end{align*}$$
where in the third line, I factor an $i$ from the right summand and apply the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

This is where I get stuck. I don't see how $\bigg[\dfrac{dx}{du} - i\dfrac{dy}{du}\bigg] = \overline{\dfrac{dz}{dw}}$. If you see a mistake please inform me, and if you know why these last two quantities are equal, please explain. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is right, you are just missing the derivation of  $dz/dw = dx/du + i dy/du$ which can be proven by taking the definition of complex differentiability in the $w=u$ direction (try?).

In other words, will study $\frac{z(u+h,v)-z(u,v)}{h}$.

Comment: Oh jeez, DUH! My excuse is that I took Complex analysis two years ago and I'm trying to complete the book that my course left unfinished. Thanks for clearing that up Evan.